# retrieve variables from SQL query in JavaScript function (rewrite)

Tags: javascript, cordova, var

I'm working on a mobile app in Apache Cordova that collects data and sends it to a web server. I would like to do that by a main function

Rewrite the code to be more focused and clear

```
//main function launched by a button
function sendData(){
    //set all var as suggested
    var content = '';
    var photoList = [];
    var fileName = '';
    //call children functions
    generateCsv(); // 1st child function
    saveCSV();     // 2nd child function
    uploadFile();  // 3rd child function
 }
```

the first function extract data from a Data Base and set new values to the above var

```
function generateCsv() { // 1st child function
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function(tx, result) {
            //do something I do not understand really... but work!
            // but set value to var!!
            console.log(content); //the new value is set correctly!!
        });
    }); 
}
```

Now if I try to log value of my three var in the next function inside the main one, I do not receive the change made by the generateCsv function...

```
function saveCSV() { // 2nd child function
    console.log(fileName); //----not updated 
    console.log(content);  //----not updated 
    console.log(photoList);//----not updated
    //do something with my vars!
}
```

last child function will upload files

```
function uploadFile(){ 3rd child function
    //do something and upload....
}
```

code complete is there:

```
//------------------SEND DATA----------------->>

function sendData(){
    var content = 'id,wateres,source,s_date,latitude,longitude,top,pump,pump_manual,other_pump,operator,operator_type,condition,disused,abandoned,access,water_presence,drinking_water,fee,fixme,note,photo,exif\n';
    var fileName = '';
    var date = new Date().toString();
    var photoList = [];
    generateCsv();

}


//---------------GENERATE CSV FILE--------------------->>
function generateCsv() {

    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function(tx, result) {
            dataset = result.rows;
            if (dataset.length!=0){

                for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) {
                    item = dataset.item(i);

                    //uploadPhoto(item['photo']);
                    photoList.push(item['photo']);

                    var exif = item['exif'].replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " | ");
                    exif = exif.replace(/,/g, '.');

                    content += item['id']+ ',' 
                            + item['wateres'] + ',' 
                            + item['source'] + ',' 
                            + item['s_date'] + ',' 
                            + item['lat'] + ',' 
                            + item['lon'] + ',' 
                            + item['top'] + ',' 
                            + item['pump'] + ',' 
                            + item['pump_manual'] + ',' 
                            + item['other_pump'] + ',' 
                            + item['operator'] + ',' 
                            + item['operator_type'] + ',' 
                            + item['condition'] + ',' 
                            + item['disused'] + ',' 
                            + item['abandoned'] + ',' 
                            + item['access'] + ',' 
                            + item['water_presence'] + ',' 
                            + item['drinking_water'] + ',' 
                            + item['fee'] + ',' 
                            + item['fixme'] + ',' 
                            + item['note'] + ',' 
                            + item['photo'] + ',' 
                            + exif + '\n';

                    fileName = item['source'] + '|' + date;
                }

                fileName = fileName.replace(/\ /g, "_");
                fileName = fileName.replace(/\,/g, "");
                fileName = fileName.replace(/\:/g, "-")+'.csv';

                $('#message').html('<p><strong>Data have been collected.</strong> </p>');

                saveCSV();
            }
        });
    });
}

//--------------------------SAVE CSV ------------------


function saveCSV() {
    console.log(fileName);

            var fileObject;
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);

            function onDeviceReady() {
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
            }

            function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
                fileSystem.root.getFile(fileName, { create: true, exclusive: false },
                    gotFileEntry, fail);
            }

            function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
                fileObject = fileEntry;
                $('#saveFile_csv').on('click', function() {
                    saveFileContent();
                    //uploadFile(fileName);
                });
            }

            function saveFileContent() {
                fileObject.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
            }

            function gotFileWriter(writer) {
                var myText = document.getElementById('my_text').value + content;
                writer.write(myText);
                writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
                    $('#message').html('<p>File contents have been written.<br /><strong>File path:</strong> ' + fileObject.fullPath + '</p>');
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                };
            }
            function fail(error) {
                alert('fail to write file code = ' + error.code);
            }

}

//----------------UPLOAD-CSV------------------------>>
function uploadFile(fileName) {

    var fileURL = "///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app/cache/"+fileName;

    function win(r) {
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        console.log("Response = " + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
        $('#contents').html('<strong>File uploaded</strong><br>'+ new Date() );
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("An error has occurred uploading file: Code = " + error.code);
        console.log("upload error source: " + error.source);
        console.log("upload error target: " + error.target);
    }

    var uri = encodeURI("http://www.website.com/upload.php");

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="text/plain";

    var headers={'headerParam':'headerValue'};

    options.headers = headers;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(fileURL, uri, win, fail, options);
    $('#contents').html('<strong>Whait upload confirmation...</strong>');
}
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set all the variable outside of function like

```
var content = '';
var fileName = '';
var date = new Date().toString();
var photoList = [];
```

and then, when you assigning any value to the variable you have to use that global variable like

```
function setVarItem()
{
    content = "test string here or value here";
}
```

Now retrieve that variable value in another function like

```
function getVarItem()
{
    alert(content) //output: test string here or value here
}
```

Comment: Hi Kirankumar Dafda and thank you for your answer. The problem I think is inside the generateCsv() function that contain an asynchronous workflow...

Comment: You have wrote all the variable locally for single function only, so you cannot use the value of that variable into another function just try creating global var and then just assign and retrieve value different functions.

Comment: Hi Hi Kirankumar Dafda, I've declared var in main function and still not work. maybe depend from asynchronous function in  generateCsv()? Thank you !

Comment: Sorry for late reply, may be you solved the problem, but still if not then you have to declare var outside of main function and then just pass value from main function